# Nginx - Checking multiple upstream and return its status

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http-status-codes, nginx-location

I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy for multiple upstream services; normal accesses are proxied to them through HTTPS depending on the host url.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;    
  location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name ~^[^\.]*be1\.example\.com$;
  include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend1;
  }
}

# And other backend configs go on...
```

For the purpose of the health check, I want to configure the location `/check.html` to return 200 by checking if **all upstreams returns 200**. However, I don't want to return any body since health check can be done through HTTP not HTTPS.
Is it possible with Nginx? And how can I do that?